# how to pass two parameters into the interface wcf

Tags: c#, json

Hello I'm developing a mobile application with wcf json. I want  pass into the web service interface two parameters, one stream and the other string, like this: wsResultImage UploadPhoto (String title, Stream image);

But I get an error: Unable to pass another parameter with Stream.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: English please.. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/ and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Posting your question in French, limits the people who can answer your question to french speakers only. Bon chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You must to use always only one parameter.

But you can create a model with these two parameters:

```
public class MyImageModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

So you can use this model as parameter:

```
public wsResultImage UploadPhoto (MyImageModel image)
{
    SaveToFile(image.Title, image.Stream);
}
```